# Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target - angular 2

Tags: angular

I am making an http get request but the Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target. How do i correct this?

```
 getFood(id){
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/routes/food_serve/v1/foodlist/'+id+'/food', options)
            .map((response:Response) => response.json());

    }
```

Comment: Do you have these imports `import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http'; import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`?

Comment: @yurzui yes i have imported them

Comment: Which exactly line is throwing the error?

Comment: @yurzui  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/routes/food_serve/v1/foodlist/'+id+'/food', options)

Comment: Which version of angular2 are you using?

Comment: my version is 1.0.0-beta.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using version 2 http.get returns an Observable so maybe that's the issue as you have no return type on the function

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

getFood(id): Observable<Response> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth.token });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/routes/food_serve/v1/foodlist/'+id+'/food', options)
        .map((response:Response) => response.json());

}
```